# Is it allowed in html to combine <ul> , <dt> and <li>?

Tags: html

To get an output like this

```
* line with bullet
  same insertion but no bullet
```

I use this code

```
<ul>
  <li>line with bullet</li>
  <dt>same insertion but without bullet</dt>
</ul>
```

May `<li>` and `<dt>` be combined this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I don't believe it complies to standards.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) Although it appears to work. There are other solutions to get what you want.

```
<ul>
  <li>line with bullet<br/>same insertion but without bullet</li>
</ul>
```

What specifically are you trying to do and why do you need this?

Comment: to get exactly that result like in your anwser :)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just break the line?

```
<ul>
  <li>This item has a bullet<br>This appears on another line, without a bullet</li>
  <li>This item has a bullet as well</li>
</ul>
```